# Extract daily data changes from mysql and rollout to timeseries DB

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, druid

In MySQL, using binlog, we can extract the data changes. But I need only the latest changes made during that time / day and need to feed those data into timeseries DB (planning to go with druid)

While reading binlog, Is there any mechanism to avoid duplicate and keep latest changes?

My intension is to get the entire MySQL DB backed up every day in a timeseries DB. It helps to debug my application for past dates by referring actual data present on that day

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka, by design, is append only log (no updates).
Kafka Connect ***source*** connector will ***continuously*** capture all the changes from binlog into the Kafka topic. Connector stores its position in binlog and will only write ***new*** changes into Kafka as they become available in MySLQ.

For consuming from Kafka, as one option, you can use ***sink*** connector that will write all the changes to your target. Or, instead of the Kafka Connect ***sink*** connector, some independent process that will read (consume) from Kafka. For Druid specifically, you may look https://www.confluent.io/hub/imply/druid-kafka-indexing-service.

Consumer (either connector or some independent process), will store its position (offset) in the Kafka topic, and will only write ***new*** changes into the target (Druid) as they become available in Kafka.

Processes described above captures all the changes and allows you to view source (MySQL) data at ***any point in time*** in target (Druid). It is the best practice to have all the changes available in the target. Use your target's functionality to limit view of data to certain time of the day, if needed.

If, for example, there are huge number of daily changes to a record in MySQL and you'd like to only write latest status as of specific time of the day to target. You'll still need to read all the changes from MySQL. Create some additional daily process that will ***read all the changes since prior run*** and filter only latest records and write them to target.